# Efficient 3D rotation using vector of angles

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine, glm-math

I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve the following:

```
ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, glm::radians(rotationVec.x), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, glm::radians(rotationVec.y), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, glm::radians(rotationVec.z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same calculation, possibly with a single function call?
The `rotationVec` is a vector of angles, similarly how the Unity engine does the gameobject rotations.

Comment: [`GLM_GTX_euler_angles`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.3/api/a00164.html)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @meowgoesthedog
this can be achieved as follows.

```
ModelMatrix = ModelMatrix * glm::eulerAngleXYZ(glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::radians(rotationVec.y), glm::radians(rotationVec.z));
```